# qTranslate for Gujarati language in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

I'm using qTranslate plugin and want my site to work in two languages, English and [Gujarati](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gujarati_language).

I want to post in these two languages from admin side and in front side one drop down will give option to select language.
The post will be of selected language.

How to get the .mo file for Gujarati to install the language in qTranslate plugin?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a support request to be placed at WordPress forums.

Comment: You'll have to start from scratch: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language . What you probably are looking for is to translate the *Theme*. Follow that link and you'll find all the info.

Answer (score 0):

In the steps below:

1. You will have to create your theme localizable by using `_()`, `__()`, `_e()` etc functions as necessary.
2. Then you run poEdit on your theme folder and create a .po file
3. Save the different languages as separate .po files. Saving the .po files would automatically transform the strings into .mo file.
4. In your template's fuctions.php you'll have to define the textdomain to load for the .mo file.

These are the basic steps if you need further assistance, comment below, I'll help.

PS> You seem to have a little confusion over .mo and qTranslate. qTranslate mainly transforms frontend and backend to enable multiple language. The .po/.mo generation has no direct relation with qTranslate.